Were CP/M systems based at $4200 a "standard"?
According to the CP/M 2 manual, the standard locations for BOOT (where you jump to do a warm start) and TBASE (the start of the transient program area or TPA) are $0000 and $0100, respectively. This obviously doesn't work if you have ROM instead of RAM at the low end of the address space, so this was moved up for certain systems.
In a discussion I was having it was noted that CP/M for the TRS-80 Model I (without a modification to bank switch RAM into $0000-$3FFF, which is normally occupied by ROM and I/O), BOOT is $4200 and TBASE is $4300. (That this seemed to be a standard for the Model I is borne out WordStar distributing their Model I version using these addresses: see Appendix E of the WordStar 3.0 Installation Manual.) This leaves $200 bytes of
RAM free between the start of RAM at $4000 and the start of CP/M.
That same manual also discusses a Heath H89/Zenith Z89 version on page B-1:

The "Heath 89 Version" is intended to run on Heath 89 and Zenith 89 computers which have ROM in the first 16K. This version is origined at 4300 Hex (rather than the usual 100 Hex) and has the terminal pre-installed.

That not only again skips over $200 bytes of RAM at $4000, but according to all the memory maps I've found, the H/Z-89 ROM extends only to $1FFF (8K) and the user RAM starts at $2000 (on an unexpanded system, 16K extending to $5FFF), so this is "wasting" more than 8K of RAM that could be available to CP/M if BASE were set lower.
It seems that CP/M for the Sinclair Spectrum before the +3 also uses the same $4200 BOOT / $4300 TBASE as the above two machines. This makes slightly more sense, since as I understand it the screen buffer needs to reside in the $4000-$7FFF block, but given that this is a much later machine than the other two, it certainly can't be the reason for those two using the same BOOT/TBASE.
So is there some reason that all these machines use the same $4200 BOOT/ $4300 TBASE? Was this some sort of informal standard used by other machines as well? What caused them to leave $200 bytes free, apparently unnecessarily, on two of these systems?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

The move is good, but we lost one useful comment from @john_e: "Regarding the original question: Only Digital Research would have been able to provide legitimate builds of CP/M where TBASE wasn't 0100h. Maybe they were reluctant to let them proliferate without good reason. (The utilities written in PL/M would be fairly simple to relocate since the interface module MCD80 has a single 'offset' equate that could be changed, but those written in assembly would need multiple edits to change the addresses of BDOS, FCB, TRAN etc; there is no provision in the ASM source for a different TPA base)."
